# Approval of App which simply redirect to a webPage

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Hi 
I have a web site for which I have created an App that when opened just opens the website URL in iPhone Safari using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`
So what are the chances for this kind of app being approved...?
Thanks.

Comment: WHY? Why would one ever use such an app? People can add a web-clip to their home screen, you know?

Comment: well its kind of a package with the hosting site. just lemme know if it can be approved or not please...

Answer (score 4):

Here are the [AppStore Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) - I would suggest reading through the specific [iOS review guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (you'll need your developer acct to view second link).  Without more details about your app, I would ask yourself if the app fits here (from the review guidelines):

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful or do not provide any lasting
>   entertainment value may be rejected
>   **2.13** Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be
>   rejected

Answer (score 1):

you /may/ be able to get away with it if you wrap some of it in phonegap. that is, put some of the files locally on the phone, and then use the network to get the rest.

Answer (score 1):

No one here can give you an authoritative answer.

Personally I would expect such an app to be rejected based on the app store guidelines.

> Apps that are not very useful or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
>   2.13
>   Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Apple would want that kind of app on the app store. You would be better off just making a mobile version of your site.